# How to pass List/Array as a parameter for JSystem Test

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

I am using JSystem for testing an API.

I wanted to know if there was any way to provide a List, or an array of limited size as a test case parameter in a Jsystem test case?

Is it possible to have a parameter to a test as say:

`Do something to the following elements with names ${elementNames}, paramsInclude={"elementNames"}` , where elementNames is an `ArrayList<String>` or `String[]` with appropriate getters and setters in the test scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the amateur question. Found out from the JSystem documentation itself (Something I had missed out).

You can set a input parameter as a String array in you test and the code would look something like this:

`Do something to the following elements with names ${elementNames}, paramsInclude={"elementNames"}`

In Jsystem, while entering parameters, separate each string with a semicolon

Initialize as `String[] elementNames= {}` in your code and appropriate getter and setter methods.

Comment: Can you please link the specific JSystem documentation?